# Binding this? Getting undefined?

Tags: jquery

```
p.test = 'hello';    

$('#btn').on('click', function(event){
    console.log(this.test); //undefined
}).bind(this);
```

I'm trying to access my var inside a click, Im using bind but it's still logging 'undefined'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `this` inside the click handler will be the DOM element which raised the event. You need to cache the reference to the `p` object outside of the handler first, then use that. Also, what are you expecting `bind(this)` to do? Bind accepts an event or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind` is placed wrong. You want to bind `this` to the event handler function, not to the jQuery collection of objects which are returned from the 'on' method.

Following sample should work:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(event){
    console.log(this.test);
}.bind(this));
```

However, it's not very good practice. Better approach could be to reference the `this` object by some private variable. Common practice is to cache the `this` object into some local variable called self, that, _this or .. etc. For example you can use following approach:

```
var self = this;

$('#btn').on('click', function(event){
    console.log(self.test);
});
```