# ES6 Function binding gets undefined (this.state captures the values)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function (with values of title and category) when a button is clicked. The values are stored in the state of the component, and the values are correct when I console.log(this.state). However, when the function is called, the value of title remains but category becomes undefined.

It works when I put the function that I want to call into another function, I'm not sure why the original binding caused one of the values to become undefined. Was "this" lost, and where was it lost at?

I have tried understanding the explanations in [React this.state is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998744/react-this-state-is-undefined) , https://javascript.info/bind , [Binding this? Getting undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25240961/binding-this-getting-undefined) and [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable) but I don't think it explains the behaviour experienced in mine.

Was I using too much this/bind which caused the problem?

```
class CreateItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputTitle: '',
            selectedCategory: ''
        }
    }

    // works when I put the createItem(title, category) inside this function
    onClickAddItem() {
        this.props.createItem(this.state.inputTitle, this.state.selectedCategory);
    }

    render() {
        <div>
        // this doesn't work (edit: due to typo where it should be selectedCategory and not inputCategory) 
        <Button text={'Create'} onClick={this.props.createItem.bind(this, this.state.inputTitle, this.state.inputCategory)}/>

        // this works
        <Button text={'Create'} onClick={this.onClickAddItem.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    }
}

// createPublicChat function is in another file

export function createItem(title, category) {
    console.log(title, category);
}
```

I expected the output of title = "BookA", category = "Fiction" to print "Book A Fiction" to console, but the actual output is "Book A undefined"

Edit: There was a typo which caused the undefined issue (as pointed out by @bkm412). Both works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is typo

```
<Button text={'Create'} onClick={this.props.createItem.bind(this, this.state.inputTitle, this.state.inputCategory)}/>
```

`this.state.inputCategory` should be changed to `this.state.selectedCategory`

Comment: binding inside `render` method is not a good idea. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36/

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed a few bad practices in this code.
The better way of calling a function with some arguments is follows:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.createItem(this.state.title, this.state.selectedcategory)} />
```

Also to prevent the binding errors, one should bind all your functions at one place i.e. inside constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputTitle: '',
            selectedCategory: ''
        }
        this.createItem = this.createItem.bind(this);
    }
```

Also you do not need to bind the functions that are passed to the component as props.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly never bind a function inside the `render` method because whenever a component is re-rendered, it'll do a new binding. If you want to bind a function the perfect place is inside the `constructor` method.

Alternatively you can use arrow functions to avoid binding issues.
e.g: `onClickAddItem=()=>{}`

Doing so you won't have to bind the class function to `this` explicitly because arrow function don't have `this` associated with it and refers to the enclosing lexical scope.

Read more about arrow function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions